# JPA criteria api, count number of grouped rows

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I need to implement paging on a query that looks like this:

`select a,b,c, sum(b) from t group by a,b,c`

in order to do this I need to count the number of rows. The easiest way to do it in SQL is with subquery on from clause:

`select count(*) from select a,b,c sum(d) from t group by a,b,c`

How to do it in criteria api? As far as I can see JPA does not support subquery in from clause (neither does Hibernate). Using native query is not an option because I have quite complex dynamic where condition, and getting the whole list just to fetch the size seems just wrong.

Comment: If you are asking for JPA Criteria API, why have you tagged the question with hibernate-criteria tag?

Comment: Also, improve your question by adding the essential parts of the entity classes and what you have tried so far

Comment: It really does not matter that much to me if it is hibernate criteria or criteria api (I can live with both even though JPA approach is preferred). What I need is being able to get the count of aggregated rows from the DB, and being able to restrict the beginning and end of the result set (setFirstResult(int), setMaxResult(int) )

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by getting a List from the first query and determining the size of the List to come up with the number of records fetched.
For Example:

```
public static List<YourTEntityClass> getDetails() {
        List<YourTEntityClass> items= null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(YourTEntityClass.class);
            cr.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.sum("b"))
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("a"))
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("c")));
            items = cr.list();
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException asd) {
            log.debug(asd.getMessage());
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return items;
    }
```

Note that you do not need to have `a` and `c` in the select list as they are already in the group list. Hibernate automatically puts them in select list.

To get the number of records:

```
List<YourTEntityClass> items= getDetails();
int count= items.size();
```

Comment: This is not JPA criteria API, it's Hibernate Criteria (which btw is now deprecated in favour of JPA criteria API)

Comment: The question is tagged that way.

Comment: Well, let's wait until the asker clarifies. However apart from the tag, the question explicitly refers to JPA, don't you think?

Comment: Even then, the Object I marked as `YourTEntityClass` needs to be of type  `javax.persistence.Entity`

Comment: As I said in the original post, fetching the whole list (~ 50k rows) just to send 100ish rows to the client (and doing so 500  times to get the whole list) seems just plain wrong. What i would like to do is being able to  slice result set on the DB side. It is trivial to do it in SQL, but not in JPA.